# Seeking an explanation of Rashi to Ⅱ Chronicles 4:11

Tags: rashi, book-of-chronicles

[Ⅱ *Divre Hayamim* 4:11](http://chabad.org/16553#showrashi=true&v=11) lists some of the items made for the first *bes hamikdash*:

> וַיַּעַשׂ חוּרָם אֶת הַסִּירוֹת וְאֶת הַיָּעִים וְאֶת הַמִּזְרָקוֹת
>
> *Churam* made the pots, shovels/brooms/rakes, and basins.

*Rashi* comments on the first of those:

> וַיַּעַשׂ חוּרָם אֶת הַסִּירוֹת — סירות נחשת שעשוים לחתות הדשן לתת לתוך הסירות

I'm having trouble understanding this. As well as I can understand it, it means:

> Copper pots that are made to rake the ashes to put them into the pots.

That is, that the pots in verse 11 are for raking ashes so that those ashes can be put into the pots. Into what pots? It doesn't read well if the ashes are to be in those same pots — they then don't need to be *put* there. And there are no other pot mentioned; anyway, if other pots were meant, I'd think *Rashi* would say so explicitly.

So what does *Rashi* mean?

Comment: Perhaps סירות here aren't pots but like the סירה, which is a type of thorny plant (commonly known today as סירה קוצנית) that was used (and still used in some places) as a kind of broom, as well as other uses.

Answer (score 3):

Based in Rashi in the parallel story in [I Melachim 7:40](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15891#showrashi=true) it would seem that the Rashi you quote has a missing heading -  the words וְאֶת הַיָּעִים.

It should be

> **וַיַּעַשׂ חוּרָם אֶת הַסִּירוֹת** — סירות נחשת. **וְאֶת הַיָּעִים**  — שעשוים לחתות הדשן לתת לתוך הסירות

This then matches Rashi in Melachim - who first says הכירות הן הן סירות and then:

> **הכיורות**. של נחשת, לדשן את המזבח:‏
>
> **The lavers**: They were of copper, [and were used] to remove the ashes therein from the altar.
>
> **היעים**. מגרפות של נחושת.  שקורין ווידו''ל באשכנז, לחתות בהן דשן בתוך הסירות: ‏
>
> **The shovels**: Copper shovels *which they call vedil and shauffel in Germany*. They were used to rake the ashes with them into the pots.

Comment: +1. Very plausible. Thanks! Now I wonder whether there are any mss. or old prints like that….

Comment: The oldest I can find seems to be the blue print of all prints - http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45706&st=&pgnum=432 with the same wording as you have.